# Trouble connecting to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to connect to a mysql database with php and myadmin. I've tried a lot of codes I could find online, but I just can't put this thing to work...
Can anyone please tell me what I might be doing wrong?
this is the php script I am using:

```
<?php

$useremail = $_POST["useremail"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

if($useremail && $password){

    // open database
    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "carlos", "nenem");

    if(!$connect){
        die ("Not able to connected to the database: " .mysql_error());
    }

    // select database
    $select_db = mysql_select_db("vergilioDB", $connect);

    if(!$connect_db){
        die("Not able to connect to the database: "  .mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_close($connect);
} else {
    die("Please enter useremail and password, or REGISTER if you are a new user!");
}

?>
```

Comment: You will need to provide more information, such as what error you are getting at what point.

Comment: What (if any) error messages are you getting?

Comment: what output do you get from this snippet? for example, what does `var_dump($connect)` placed right after `mysql_connect` say?

Comment: You may notice a trend based on the above comments. (We need the specific error message to diagnose this problem.) That said, it's most likely an incorrect DB username/password combination, or the user you're attempting to use doesn't have rights from the host you're using (if it's a separate DB server).

Comment: it's going straight to the message: ""Please enter useremail and password, or REGISTER if you are a new user!""

Comment: @Karl - then check you have both password and useremail set in `$_POST` (try `var_dump($_POST)` to see)

Answer (score 2):

Carefull, `$select_db` != `$connect_db`

The variable names are different, rewrite to:

```
$select_db = mysql_select_db("vergilioDB", $connect);
if(!$select_db){
     die("Not able to connect to the database: "  .mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: @Lekensteyn How about `[happens-to-the-best-of-us]`?

Comment: I am totally new to this thing. I am learning programming by reading books and looking at online examples. Thanks you all for your support. :)

Comment: @djacobson: we are all human - and human err @Karl: if this [answer] answers your question, mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

note that you are closing your MySQL connection regardless of anything else before you ever use it for anything..

```
mysql_close($connect);
```

You likely want to separate your connection logic from your login logic. You likely need the DB connection to validate the password no matter what and your DB connection should be the first thing you do to make sure you can even DO anything with a given page...